# Install conjure-up via snap Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, server, openstack, snap, conjure-up

When I try to install conjure-up, I get the fallowing error :

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Mount snap "core" (1689) ([start snap-core-1689.mount] failed with exit status 1: Job for snap-core-1689.mount failed. See "systemctl status snap-core-1689.mount" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
)
```

Any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: You'll probably want to start with gathering `snap version` and cross posting to https://forum.snapcraft.io/ for further help. This seems snap specific and not conjure-up